# Problem with Cauchy Principal Value Integral

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

I'm having problems with this integral

$$\int_{a \sqrt \alpha}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{x^2 - a^2 \alpha})(e^x - 1)} \, dx \qquad \text{with } a, \alpha > 0$$

I tried to solve it with Maple, using the Cauchy Principal Value function, but it doesn't deliver. Any suggestions? Thought also about considering the Fourier series around the $a\sqrt{\alpha}$ value, but I get the worst integrals ever!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

The presence of $\sqrt{x^2-u^2}~$ begs for a [hyperbolic substitution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSubstitution.html) of the form $x=u\cosh t$. This will inevitably yield a $($non-trivial$)$ integrand containing $e^{\large u\cosh t}$ in its expression. The only functions known to possess such a form are the [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function). Unfortunately, even they seem unable to help us. The only other solution would be expanding the integrand into a [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and switching the order of summation and integration, then rewriting it in terms of some $($rather hideous$)$ [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). But it is very doubtful whether such an approach will yield any $($meaningful$)$ results.

Comment: Perhaps a third option would be to rewrite the integral as an infinite series of Bessel functions, by combining the two methods described above.

Comment: This integral appears in the Theory of Superconductivity.